# Test symmetricity for a sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

I have a sparse matrix in LIL (List of Lists) format. I want to test whether the matrix is symmetric or not. Let's say I have `n` non-default elements. What's the best complexity in terms or space and time I can achieve?

The best solution I have came up with so far is to traverse the matrix, looking at each non-default element (consisting of row, col and value) and storing that element in a hash-table and then checking whether two elements Element$(i, j, v_1)$ and $(j, i, v_2)$ have the same value or not. The time complexity for this is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ and space complexity is also $\mathcal{O}(n)$. It looks to me no scope of improvement in time complexity but I wonder whether space complexity could be improved or not without compromising the time complexity.

Comment: As you need to scan the whole LIL once, time complexity is indeed $\Omega(n)$. With $O(1)$ storage all you can do is in time $O(n^2)$ worst-case, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

For sparse matrices we often uses either compressed sparse row format (CSR) or compressed sparse column format (CSC).

In CSR format there are three array, XADJ[n+1], ADJ[nnz] and VAL[nnz].
Information about the nonzero entries on the ith row is stored in at in a contiguous chunk of ADJ and VAL starting at index XADJ[i]. Specifically, 
ADJ[k] is the column index of the kth nonzero entry of the matrix and VAL[k] is the value of the kth nonzero. Normally, XADJ[n+1]=nnz stores the number of non-zero entries of the matrix. In this manner, CSR format allows convenient access to the rows of matrix. Similar, CSC format allows convenient access to the columns of the matrix

In your case, you can benefit from using a hybrid format. Specifically use CSR format for the strictly upper triangular part of the matrix and CSC format for the strictly lower triangular format, storing the diagonal entries in a separate array. This will allow you to determine that the matrix is symmetric in time proportional to the number of non-zeros and you can do the comparison in place with no extra storage.

You will have to adapt your other routines (sparse matrix vector multiply and LU factorization) to this format and that extra work may not be worth the effort.

Regardless, if you are using pointers and dynamic memory allocation to implement your linked list, then you stand to gain tremendously by switching to the more compact representation afforded by either CSR or CSC.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Just an idea** Maybe you can try and take a few random vectors, transpose and multiply from left and right separately and compare the resulting vectors. The probability that they become the same by chance for any non-symmetric matrix should diminish quite fast - but they must be exactly the same in all elements including precision if matrix is symmetric. Of course you will be 100% sure (up to numerical precision) after having tried $m$ (given $m \times m$ matrix) of them if that is necessary.

---

**EDIT** To expand a little, I did a small script randomizing a double precision sparse symmetric $m = 50$, with $n=200$, probability that an any one element gets altered ( destroying symmetricity ) is $1\%$ for each element.

Out of 1024 such randomized matrices and single random vectors such we successfully found $667$ which were correctly non-symmetric and $8$ which missed. We would expect $1- 0.99^{100} \approx 0.63397$ which is close to $\frac{667}{1024} \approx 0.63672$.

---

**NEW EDIT** I found that the 8 failed ones above occured when accidentally altering a diagonal element, now it consistently finds all non-symmetric matrices $100\%$ on the first vector try.

---

**Analysis of complexity**

The memory complexity will be very nice as you can compute each element at a time and compare pairwise and just store a boolean "have we differed yet?". Computational complexity for one core is $\mathcal{O}(m)$, but for k cores it will be $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m}{k}\right)$ as it is massively parallellizable, just let each core compute $m/k$ element pairs. Memory requirements is need to store two element, which should easily fit into registers of modern cpus. Then "or"-ing all the cores' booleans tells us if one (or more) have differed yet and then we can stop execution. No need for locking memory as we can only go from false to true and not the other way. So we are done when each thread finishes or as fast as the first thread finds a difference.

---

I have mostly worked in applied sciences with floating point matrices and not considered integers or finite fields of integers, so maybe that is a different story.

Comment: Suppose the matrix entries are integers and the matrix is $m \times m$, $m \le n$.  Take a prime $p$ small enough that addition and multiplication mod $p$ are $O(1)$, let the entries of $x$ be uniformly distributed random numbers mod $p$, and do the matrix-vector multiplications mod $p$.  If your matrix $A$ is not symmetric, the probability that $Ax \ne (x^T A)^T$ is at most $1/p^2$.  And this computation is $O(n)$ in time (assuming you can generate your random vector $x$ in $O(n)$ time).

Comment: Another word of caution: Sparse matrix vector multiply has very low arithmetic intensity as it does O(1) flops pr. word. Modern computer hardware favors dense operation and have done so for the last 20-25 years. Sparse calculations typically run on supercomputer at around 2% of the peak flop rate because the memory and network latency is too high. In the time it takes to do one sparse matrix vector multiply a direct method based on a suitable memory layout will have made a bit wise comparison of the entries. Probabilistic algorithms.should be avoided when the wrong result can cause harm.

Comment: Depends a lot on the size and structure of the matrix, how the memories and caches are arranged and how the software is written. One good thing about it is that we don't need to keep track of which elements of the matrix we've checked or anything, that is : intermediate storage required is basically $O(0)$, and we don't need to develop or fiddle with any advanced data structures in doing so. Also is really easy to parallellize / vectorize which is nice for modern multi-cored machines of the last 5-10 years or so.

Comment: You are advocating an approach which gives a nondeterministic answer in deterministic time. This is *not* appropriate for applications were a wrong answer can cause harm or loss of life. By storing an $n$ by $n$ sparse matrix using CSR format for the strictly upper triangular part and CSC format for the lower triangular part you can determine if the matrix is structurally symmetric using O(nnz) time and no extra storage. If it is structurally symmetric than you need O(nnz) time to compare the value of the nnz nonzero elements in place. Both phases can be done with perfect vectorial intensity.

Comment: Tell that to a doctor. They use statistics all the time to make diagnoses. Because in reality resources to make decisions are constrained, as they are in computers. By the way a common reason to check for symmetricity to decide which algorithm to perform a calculation with. So the check can't take too long or the time gains of choosing a faster algorithm would be eaten up by the algorithm to decide which of them to use.

Comment: Medicine relies on numerical linear algebra be done quickly, accurately and reliably. Statistics are appropriate when the is *no* deterministic alternative. There is a fast, deterministic alternative here. The speed gain from knowing that matrix is symmetric *far* outweighs the cost of determining symmetry. A LDLT factorization of a symmetric matrix requires half the number of operations of an LU factorization of a general matrix. The problem of solving a stable Lyaponov matrix equation goes from being virtually intractable to trivial if the matrix is known to be symmetric.

Comment: I still haven't found even one non-symmetric matrix not possible to disqualify by just one iteration so maybe it is not even probabilistic. It would be interesting to know if there is one or to prove why there can't be one. You are welcome to try and find a counter example or proof if you want to. At least that's a mathematical question.